# How to make report in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, rdlc

I want to make this kind of report in ASP.NET C#. I've tried with RDLC and Crystal Report but there are some columns to marge. So I haven't found any way to marge column. Can anyone help me to make this kind of report?
[[image: Image preview]]

I've already made a row group but it's at the begin of table, at the end of table the row group is not workable
[[image: Image preview]]

```
ReportViewer1.Reset();

//Data Source
DataTable dt = GetData();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

//Path
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report3.rdlc";

//Refresh
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();


private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connStr = @"Data Source= OVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database =RdlcDB; Integrated Security= true;";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  CustomerID ,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Address,City,Country,Phone FROM Customers",cn);
        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]in rdlc design you can set groups at the end, please see this link:
[grouping in rdlc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services)

Comment: Do not post link only answers. Please copy relevant parts from the page and paste it into your answers body.

Comment: Sajjad Ali : in your answer  the row group is at the front of table ,,,,i need this at end of table... plz try it and let me know how i can design exactly same as my fig:1